# The number of generators of a submodule over a Principal Ideal Ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Can someone give me a hint in proving that if a module $M=\langle m_1,\dots,m_n\rangle$ is generated by $n$ elements over a principal ideal (commutative) ring, then every submodule can be generated by at most the same number of elements?

I think with some hints I will be able to get it. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "...then every submodule is generated also *by at most* the same..."?

Comment: I think it must be so @Theorem, otherwise the submodule $\,\langle m_1\rangle\,$ contradicts that...

Comment: @DonAntonio : yes!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use induction on $n$.  Also, the second isomorphism theorem (if $L$ and $N$ are submodules of $M$, $(L+N)/N \cong L/(L \cap N)$) may come in handy.

I found this to be a pretty tricky exercise, but a very good one.  The hints I gave won't give the solution away, but should get you started.